# How to calculate if the location of geomorphological locations are likely to be in the proximity of geological faults

Tags: distance, spatial-statistics

I have two shapefile data. One is point data with 800+ observations of certain geomorphologic features in karst and other is a line shapefile which represents faults (geology). I want to know if there is any relationship between those two, or more specifically I would like to know if there are significantly more points near the faults.

Do you know of any functions that would help me with this?

Comment: You could use v.distance from the toolbox to determine the minimum distance between each feature and fault lines and then do some statistical magic (basically check, whether the majority of your features is further away or closer to the fault lines than they would be assuming a random distribution, as in mean vs. median).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just a generic description unconnected to any specific GIS software...

Assuming we have faults and some points (1), probably we can start with (2) `rasterize` these faults.

[image]

Then we will create (3) `proximity raster` which shows distance from faults, followed by (4) `extract cell values` at locations of the karst (point) features.

[image]

These data can be examined by histograms (or any graph) to understand the relationship between distance and occurrence.(5, 6)

[image]

If you have specific GIS software in mind, there would be more straightforward ways.

Comment: Thank you for your input. I did not understand how is occurence calculated?  I've had an idea to create a series of 100 m buffers around faults, and then count the number of points in each buffer. Then I would examine if there is a statistically significant difference between the groups. However, it would be ideal to do all this in QGIS or R.

Comment: @davorkorman Just about the count of occurrence; save the point layer (4) as csv file. Graphs (5, 6) are done by Excel but R hist() would be easier.

Comment: An update, in QGIS there is a Point sampling tool from which you can extract raster cell values for your points. Is there test to calculate if there is statistical difference in number of occurences based on distance, or this graphical examination (histograms for example) are the only way to derive conlcusions?